# FlotJS tooltip messing with the responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, flot

I am working on an application where I am using FlotJS charting library to plot graphs and I have turned on the tooltips so that users can hover over points and can tell the content of each point on a particular date.

Like in [this interactive graph example by flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/), we can hover over the points to see the values of sin and cos.

I am using the [Smart Admin Responsive Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-frontend-BSH01) in my project and if you navigate to the demo of graphs they are offering, there is also a section on [Flot Chart Demos](http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/#ajax/flot.html)

If you look closely on the Sin Chart which is second in order, it is similar to what I am doing. Hovering over the points presents tooltips to view the value of sin.

The problem I am facing is that if you hover over the last few points, the tooltip appears but it messes with the responsiveness of the page and is not visible per say.

How to go around this problem? Is there some way I can make the tooltip appear to the left of the mouse pointer when it is on the end of the page?

**EDIT**

**Options Object**

```
var layerOptions = {
    xaxis : {
        mode : "time"
    },
    legend : {
        show : true,
        noColumns : 1, // number of colums in legend table
        labelFormatter : null, // fn: string -> string
        labelBoxBorderColor : "#000", // border color for the little label boxes
        container : null, // container (as jQuery object) to put legend in, null means default on top of graph
        position : "ne", // position of default legend container within plot
        margin : [0, 5], // distance from grid edge to default legend container within plot
        backgroundColor : "#efefef", // null means auto-detect
        backgroundOpacity : 0.4 // set to 0 to avoid background
    },
    tooltip : true,
    tooltipOpts : {
        content : "<b>%s</b> content on <b>%x</b> was <b>%y</b>",
        dateFormat : "%y-%m-%d",
        defaultTheme : false
    },
    grid : {
        hoverable : true,
        clickable : true
    },
    series: {
        /*bars: {
            show: true, 
            barWidth: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            order: 1
        }*/
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the position of the tooltip dynamically depending on window size. I use this in one of my flot pages to flip the tooltip to the left when near the right border:

```
var prevPoint = null;
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if (prevPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            prevPoint = item.dataIndex;
            $("#tooltip").remove();

            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2),
                text = item.series.label + ' content on ' + x + ' was ' + y;
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, text);
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        prevPoint = null;
    }
});

function showTooltip(x, y, content) {
    var cssParams = {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        border: '1px solid #888888',
        padding: '2px',
        'background-color': '#eeeeee',
        opacity: 0.8
    };
    if (x < 0.8 * windowWidth) {
        cssParams.left = x + 3;
    }
    else {
        cssParams.right = windowWidth - x + 6;
    }
    if (y < 0.8 * windowHeight) {
        cssParams.top = y + 3;
    }
    else {
        cssParams.bottom = windowHeight - y + 6;
    }
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + content + '</div>').css(cssParams).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100);
}
```

`windowHeight` and `windowWidth` are global variables which are updated in the resize event (using `$(window).height()`). You can also use the dimensions of a container element if you like.

You can remove the tooltip plugin and options when you use the given events/functions.

Comment: Thanks for he quick response. The code is making sense to me but I am new to Flot and I am not sure where to place this method and how to supply it with the x, y and content variables. And should I use `div#tooltip` or `div#flotTip`? Because flot is using the second one. I am confused.

Comment: Ah, you use the tooltip plugin. I thought you did it manually like in the [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/) you linked. See the edited questions for the needed code. (The plugin uses similar but slightly more complex code.)

Comment: I tried this but did not work. I set the `windowWidth = $(window).width();` and `windowHeight = $(window).height();`. I took out the options for the tooltip plugin. I removed the load method for the tooltip plugin too, but still for some reason it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: I tried to `console.log('foo')` and `console.log('bar')` from both the `bind` method as well as `showTooltip`, and they fire up as they should. When I hover over the graph, it logs 'foo' and when I am over a point, it logs 'bar'. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, now I changed it to `windowWidth = $(window).width();` and `windowHeight = $(window).height();` and it is working now but there is still a small removing issue. If the points are too close, a number of them show up simultaneously and then the last one fades in but the other don't, unless I move pointer on the graph some where which calls the plothover event and it removes them one by one on each call. Am I making sense? Let me know if you have any idea how to get around this problem. Anyway thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @Rohan I updated the answer with code to prevent simultaneous tooltips using the variable `prevPoint` to save for which datapoint the tooltip is shown.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra effort. I will try this code as soon as possible and let you know. :)